# Python, separating all lowercase string at position where the upper string is

Tags: python

I can't find a way to create a thing that goes from `"BlackWhite", "OrangeBlue"` to `"Black" ,"White", "Orange", "Blue"`

I could use something like

```
string = "BlackWhite"
for i in len(string):
   if string[i].isupper:
      name1 = string[I:]
      name2 = string[:I]
```

but I don't know how to make it avoid the first letter.

Comment: what do you mean by *avoid first letter*?

Comment: Can there be more than one uppercase character in *the middle*?

Answer (score 1):

```
string = "BlackWhite"
for i in range(1, len(string)):
   if string[i].isupper:
      name1 = string[i:]
      name2 = string[:i]
```

That way you skip over the first letter in the string.

Comment: I assume you didn't run this code as it fails with, "NameError: name 'I' is not defined".  (I assume the person who upvoted didn't run it either.)

Comment: Corrected it. I just copied it from the question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use range to skip the first letter and start from 2nd

```
for i in range (1, len(string)):
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how you can do that with [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):**

```
import re
words = ["BlackWhite", "OrangeBlue"]
w = [a for s in words for a in re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',s)]
print(w)
```

Output:

```
['Black', 'White', 'Orange', 'Blue']
```

---

---

**If you only have individual strings (not in a list):**

```
import re
word = 'BlackWhite'
print(re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',word))
```

Output:

```
['Black', 'White']
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably after `re.split` with a lookahead/lookbehind pair to detect the `[a-z][A-Z]` pattern (and an optional `-` character per your comment):

```
>>> s = "BlackWhite OrangeBlue fooBar GreenYellowRed Black-White"
>>> re.split(r"\s+|(?<=[a-z])-?(?=[A-Z])", s)
['Black', 'White', 'Orange', 'Blue', 'foo', 'Bar', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Red', 'Black', 'White']
```

I tossed in the `\s+` to split on spaces too, but you can omit this if all you have is the lone word pair.

Comment: oh nice ! thank you ! How would one like that look to seperate Black-White ? the "-" has to go

Comment: Added, but traditionally you should ask that in the question.

Answer (score 0):

`re.split` is another way, e.g.

```
re.split('([A-Z][a-z]+)', 'BlackWhite')
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex would be the best solution..

```
test_str = "BlackWhite"
import re
test_list = re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]*', test_str)
print(test_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

When iterating use `enumerate` if you also need a reference to the index.  When you check if a character is upper case also check if the index is zero.

```
s = "BlackWhite"
for i,c in enumerate(s):
   if i != 0 and c.isupper():
      name1 = s[i:]
      name2 = s[:i]
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an opportunity to abuse `itertools.groupby()` and let it do the separation of letters for us:

```
from itertools import groupby

string = "BlackWhiteOrangeBlue"

words = []

for isupper, letters in groupby(string, str.isupper):
    if isupper:
        words.append(*letters)
    else:
        words[-1] += ''.join(letters)

print(words)
```

OUTPUT

```
> python3 test.py
['Black', 'White', 'Orange', 'Blue']
>
```